# Getting content of an object in node.js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

I have an object 'res' and it holds a field:

```
res.headers=new object();
```

im using this field as a map which holds key and value meaning:

```
res.headers['key']='value';
```

is there any way to get the content of this map by iterating it without knowing the key?

thank you!

Comment: Just a small note: nobody really uses the 'new object()' syntax, instead 'res.headers = {};' should be used for new objects and '[]' for new arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var key in res.headers) {
    if(res.headers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + res.headers[key]);
    }
}
```

or with `Object.keys()`:

```
for(var key in Object.keys(res.headers)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + res.headers[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing to do is use a javascript library, like [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#values) for example, then use someting like:

```
arr = _.values(res.headers)
arr[0] // value of first element
```